# jQuery .animate() not working when using a variable as css parameter

Tags: jquery

I am currently working on some jQuery to animate some sliding panels on my website.
My code looks good and I don't get any error but still the animate() function doesn't work.

Here is what I achieved to make:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.matches('.ear')) {
      var parent = $(event.target).parent();
      if (parent.attr('data-toggled') == 'false') {
        var direction = parent.data('side');
        var distance = '0';
        parent.animate({direction: distance}, 500);
        parent.attr('data-toggled', true);
      } else {
        var direction = parent.data('side');
        var distance = '-20%';
        parent.animate({direction: distance}, 500);
        parent.attr('data-toggled', false);
      }
    };
  });
});
```

`.ear` is the class of the images I want to use as "triggers" to slide my panes in and out. When the `.click()` event is triggered on a `.ear`, its parent's `data-slide` is read in order to know which pane will be triggered and to indicate the `.animate()` in which direction the pane is supposed to be slided.
To avoid having too much lines and cases, I made a `direction` variable in which I store the css property I want to be changed and the value of this change.
The code seems to run entirely (I tried to `console.log()` the `.animate()` function, which seems to work, and the `data-toggled` switches from true to false) but my browser doesn't seem to execute if.

I keep trying to get a fix but nothing works so far.

EDIT:

The animate function should be like `parent.animate({left: "0"},500);` when I click on the left pane for the first time as I want it to slide in.

Here is [my website](http://www.baguetteinc.tk) so you can have a clear view of what I would like to achieve

Comment: You're making your code rather difficult to read and maintain by constructing an object in `direction`. Better to use separate vars for `side` and the numeric value, I think, and using them in the `animate()` method.

Comment: I tried to delete the simple quotes as seen on some posts over the internet but I have the "Unexpected token ." error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery animate function doesn't accept variables like that because it doesn't require the quotes on the parameter.

Consider this:

```
parent.animate({
    left: '100'
}, 500);
```

vs

```
var left = 'right';
parent.animate({
    left: '100'
}, 500);
```

The ambiguity around the second block is exactly why you can't use variables. 
Instead use something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(window).click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.matches('.ear')) {
      var parent = $(event.target).parent();
      if (parent.attr('data-toggled') == 'false') {
        var direction = parent.data('side');
        var distance = '100';
        if (direction == 'left') {
            parent.animate({left: distance}, 500);
        } else if (direction == 'right') {
            parent.animate({right: distance}, 500);
        }
        parent.attr('data-toggled', true);
      } else {
        var direction = parent.data('side');
        var distance = '0';
        if (direction == 'left') {
            parent.animate({left: distance}, 500);
        } else if (direction == 'right') {
            parent.animate({right: distance}, 500);
        }
        parent.attr('data-toggled', false);
      }
    };
  });
});
```

[JSfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/h3d7s6cm/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Looks like I will have to add some if/else then.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a string to `animate()`: `"{left: "-20%"}"`. You can verify this by placing a breakpoint in your dev tools Sources panel at the line after and inspecting the value.

Instead, construct an actual object directly in the `animate()` argument:

```
var direction = parent.data('side');
var distance = '-20%';

parent.animate({
    direction: distance
}, 500);
```

I think you'll agree that this is much easier to read as well.

Comment: I tried this earlier and it doesn't work either, I don't really get why, it looks like the animate() function isn't using the variables values but the variables names

Comment: Were you using quotes where you shouldn't have been? Neither the key nor the value should be quoted.

Comment: I edited my code on the OP according to what you told me in this answer, it still doesn't work. Feel free to try it yourself with the link in the OP

Comment: Well shoot. I'm stumped and out of time for now.